# How to use a constructor interface as a generic type constraint?

Tags: typescript

Let's say, I would like to define an interface (or, *protocol*) which requires its implementing types to be constructable from strings:

```swift
protocol StringDecodable {
    init(string: String) throws
}
```

This interface shall be used in a generic class which, for the sake of simplicity, just loads a string from a URL and creates an instance of the generic type from it:

```swift
struct DataStore<T: StringDecodable> { 
    func fetchingResult() throws -> T { 
        let contents = try String(contentsOf: self.url, encoding: .utf8) 
        return try T(string: contents) 
    } 
    let url: URL 
}
```

For a type conforming to this interface, the class can then be used in the following way:

```swift
struct Time: StringDecodable {
    init(string: String) throws {
        (self.hours, self.minutes) = try parseTheTimeString(string)
    }
    let hours: Int
    let minutes: Int    
}

let dataStore = DataStore<Time>(url: URL(string: "https://whattimeisit.org/")!)
let time = try dataStore.fetchingResult()
```

How would I translate this pattern to TypeScript?

**My approach:**

I tried doing it this way:

```js
interface StringDecodable {
    new (s: string): this;
}

class DataStore<T extends StringDecodable> {
    constructor(private readonly url: URL) {}

    async fetchResult(): Promise<T> {
        const response = await fetch(this.url);
        const contents = await response.text();
        return new T(contents);
    }
}
```

However, this is giving me a compiler error on the expression `new T(contents)` saying:

```
'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)
```

Comment: Type metadata is erased in transpilation, what exists at runtime is _only JavaScript_. So you need some concrete argument to have a value, e.g. `new() => T`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Always forgetting about this. Seems like there is no way to _directly_ translate this to TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true that the metadata is lost, thus there's nothing that you can do about it.

However you can leverage the TypeScript inference to infer the type that you want to create dynamically.

You could go with the following approach

```
interface IStringDecodable<T> {
    new(s: string): T;
}

class DataStore<T> {
    constructor(private service: IStringDecodable<T>, private readonly url: URL) {}
    
    async fetchResult() : Promise<T> {
        const response = await fetch(this.url);
        const contents = await response.text();
        return new this.service(contents);
    }
}
```

Basically you are passing the type as parameter and TypeScript will infer it allowing the type check.

Below is how to use it:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(s: string) {}
}

const dataStore = new DataStore(MyClass, new URL("Test"));
const ret = dataStore.fetchResult();
```

At end, ret will be of type `MyClass`.
It would be better working only with generics, but the inference it works similarly, and it will safety guarantee you the type that you want.

Comment: This comes closer to the original intention (have thus marked this as accepted).
(As a minor remark though, maybe the `<T extends Record<…>>` clause is not absolutely necessary, but could be replaced by just `<T>`.)

Comment: True, it is not necessary. The example that I gave to you is from a real case that I use, I just forgot to clean it.

Answer (score 0):

As [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) mentioned, the type `T` will no longer exist in the resulting JavaScript. Thus, the code will not compile.

Perhaps one way to mimic this pattern would be to get rid of the `StringDecodable` interface and turn `DataStore` into an abstract class with a `parseString()` method to be implemented by subclasses:

```js
abstract class DataStore<T> {
    constructor(private readonly url: URL) {}

    async fetchResult(): Promise<T> {
        const response = await fetch(this.url);
        const contents = await response.text();
        return this.parseString(contents);
    }

    protected abstract parseString(contents: string): T;
}
```

A concrete subclass for the particular type could then provide the parsing functionality:

```js
class TimeDataStore extends DataStore<Time> {
    protected parseString(contents: string): Time {
        return new Time(...);
    }
}
```